# How can I map app permission names from the azure portal to permission ID's returned by the azure cli

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the azure cli to automate app management, but I don't see a way to map ID's returned by the [`az ad app permission list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_permission_list) to permission names found on the app page in the portal.

The only way I've found to look up permisison ID by permission name is to:

- go to the portal
- go to an empty app
- open the add permission page
- select the permission you want to look up
- open the browsers network tab
- add the permission
- look at the payload to see what ID is returned as part of the request
- delete the permission
- repeat for all permission you want to look up

I can follow a similar process to look up permission name by ID using the cli, but both are incredibly tedious.

I'm not particularly familiar with Microsoft in general, so I'm sure I'm just missing something. Is there a way to look up permission name by permission ID or permission ID by permission name in a more reasonable way?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Graph permission mapping is found here: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=displayName eq 'Microsoft Graph'